# How can I reuse and html navbar on each page of my website?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am using Bootstrap 4 for my website.

Each page includes the same navbar code. When I change the navbar, I have to copy the code to each page.

How can I make one file with the navbar code and include it in every page at runtime, thereby making it possible to update the navbar once and have it display the same on every page?

I know how to do this in php but I prefer to use javascript.

I made a test page using examples found on other sites but it doesn't work, see http://vidalingua.com/nav-test.html

Comment: Take a look at https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your site you are loading jquery in the head and then loading jquery slim in the foot of your page.  In jquery slim load() is not supported.  Instead of loading 2 versions of jquery lust load the full version of jquery in your foot section and place your jquery code after that.  Here is how your page should look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>

<body>

<!--Navigation bar-->
<div id="nav-placeholder">

</div>


<!--end of Navigation bar-->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("navbar.html");
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! I copied your code to https://vidalingua.com/nav-test2.html but it didn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: My fault the crossorgin integrity encoding was faulty replace your script code for the link to jquery with the following: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` and it should work.  I will edit the answer as well.

Comment: Hey Steve, I got your code to work by substituting line below for jquery include. 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: Steve, your update worked as well. I've left it in https://vidalingua.com/nav-test2.html Thanks!

Comment: There is an issue with this technique and that's the Google Page Crawl. Google and other bots will not find the other pages if the nav bar is included this way. Does anybody have a workaround for this?

Comment: @Dezze The OP wanted a javascript answer to this.  You can use the backend to dynamically add your navbar on page request but this specific question was how to achieve this with javascript.  If you have a node server you can do this with javscript and nodejs or you can use php and a number of backend technologies to achieve this but that is not really what the question was about. Also google will more than likely run your javscript but other engines won't.

Comment: @not_fubar_yet bootstrap 5 doesn't use jquery you have to load jquery on your own if you want to use a jquery script read the docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/ if you don't want to use jquery then use javascript only ajax request https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var filename = "https://www.vidalingua.com/navbar.html"
        $("#includedContent").load(filename);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="includedContent"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```